# How to remove matching dynamic string portion from a variable in bash

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I need to remove a specific portion " [PR:xxxxxxx] " of string from "Tag" variable as follows:

Input:

```
Tag=[Archived][PR:John][Finished]
```

Output:

```
Tag=[Archived][Finised]
```

Note: "xxxxxxxx" is changed time to time

Comment: BTW, some friendly advice: On stack exchange sites it's strongly encouraged to share what approach you
have tried so far (preferably in the form of some code, if applicable). Many
users don't want to spend their time simply doing people's coding tasks for
them, but all users are happy to _help_ you solve a problem! (not my downvote btw, but I'm sure this is likely the reason someone else downvoted your question). Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @glenn jackman for pointing out a limitation in my original answer.

You could use this sed command:

```
sed 's/\[PR:[^]]*\]//' your_file
```

It matches the `[PR:` part followed by any number of non `]*`  characters (with
`[^]]`) up until the next `]` and deletes it

If you want to do the replacement in-place (i.e. overwrite the contents of the
your_file, you can add the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i 's/\[PR:[^]]*\]//' your_file
```

This page https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html explains Sed very well if you
want to learn it.

Comment: `.*` is too greedy. What if `Tag=[Archived][PR:John][ImportantTag][Finished]`? Instead use `s/\[PR:[^]]*\]//`

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman - I updated the answer accordingly for future people.